# Regular expression to avoid duplicate numbers separated by comma

Tags: regex, apex

I have a string like `622,645,677,622,689,673,622`.

I want to remove the duplicates from the above string.

I have tried with `(\d{3},)*` but the duplicates were not detected.

How should I modify the expression to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Depending on what you are going to do with those numbers in the string and how many there are of them, there may be better ways.

Comment: Regex isn't the best tool for stuffs like this. Split the string at the comma and then select for distinct values.

Comment: they occur any number of times, i just want to remove the duplicate numbers.

Comment: What programming environment will you use ? A regex pattern only allows for detection, but you want to transform the string.

Comment: i will use apex.......can we avoid duplicates using regex????

Comment: Is that APEX, as in Oracle Application Express, or Apex, as in salesforce.com?

Comment: If you are writing that in a normal programming environment, just split with comma and remove dupes. No need in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have are numbers, this might work.
*This doesn't address the viability of integers though, just characters.*

`\b(\d+)(?=.*?\1\b)\b`

Using a backreference, it matches if a number exists downstream using a lookahead.

`\b(\d+)(?=.*?\b\1\b)\b`

Replace with nothing.

Formatted:

```
 \b 
 ( \d+ )                       # (1)
 (?= .*? \b \1 \b )
 \b
```